Which Criminal Minds episode showed the first time Aaron Hotchner and David Rossi work together?
I remember watching a scene in an episode in which there is a flashback which shows Aaron Hotchner running up to David Rossi from behind as Rossi arrives at the scene of a murder investigation. I've been trying to find it but just haven't been able to find out which episode it was. As far as I can recollect, the flashback was set before Rossi had retired from the BAU and it was the first time Hotch was meeting Rossi at a time when Hotch was a junior agent.
Thanks in advance to anyone who answers my question. It's killing me, not being able remember.

It's "Profiling 101" from Season 7


It's a flashback from 1997. The killer surfaced again after a few years of silence. Rossi arrives at the dump site of the latest victim and meets Hotch there (who's working at Seattle at that time)
